# Keeping a absolute div aligned with percentage parent div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using a div, and inside that div another div which needs to stick to the parent div.

**But when i rescale the browser there's it's not sticking to the right place.** Do i need to do this with javascript?

HTML

```
<div class="block">
    White div block
    <div class="block-content">
        Green div
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.block {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-image: url('voorgrond.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 70% center; /* positie van de screen */

}

.block-content {
position: absolute;
left: 65%;
top: 42%;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
}
```

The green dot should stick inside the white square.

[image]

Comment: do you have html or php code you could post here?

Comment: Thanks for the CSS. How about your HTML? Would be awesome if you could provide a working JSFiddle too!

Comment: I added the HTML, it's pretty simple. Thanks for your response!

Comment: Oh Sorry. The .block-content is the green one, It should stick with the .block div.

Comment: @MiguelStevens assuming `voorgrond` is the white square, where's the image for the green dot? Do these have to be images (CSS can make both of these objects)

Comment: Hi, the green div is just for an example, It's not an image. It should be a div, sticking to the position of another div. Sorry if it's not that clear

Comment: @MiguelStevens http://jsfiddle.net/VD22L/ ??

Comment: We'll the problem is that the parent div ( the white one ) is 100% width, So it's responsive to a browser resize, This is where the green dot doesn't stick to the white div.

Comment: @MiguelStevens I think you need to apply fix value (like 5px) of left (not in percentage like 65%) in .block-content style sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your goal is the image I made this fiddle which mimics what you seem to need.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/v68W6/12/)

HTML:

```
<div class="block">
    <div class="block-content">
        Hierzo!
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.block{
    position:relative;
    margin: 300px 0 0 50%;
    width:30%;
    height:80px;
    background:grey;
    border-radius:10px;
}

.block-content{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:green;
    border-radius:50px;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin: -25px 0 0 -25px;
}
```

Hope this helps!

**EDIT** Added responsive width to `.block`

Comment: Thank you! almost there. Now the problem is my .block div has a percentage width, to fit to the browser window. Or is this not done? Should i give it a px based width?

Comment: I updated the fiddle and my answer, now .block has responsive width

Answer (score 1):

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/AKiGAVa/2/)

```
<div class="block">
    <div class="block-content"></div>
</div>
```

```
.block {
  position: absolute;
  background:#fff;
  border-radius:10%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;  
  padding:50px;
  left: 65%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -150px;
  margin-left: -150px;
}

.block-content {
  position: absolute;
  background: #00A652;
  border-radius:50%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .block{
      left: 50%;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! One litle problem is when I want the .block (parent) to be percentage based width? How would I go about that. or isn't that possible with plain css?

Comment: @MiguelStevens first setup a valid example, than you can expect some reliable answers, what you posted, both images and code do not reflect anything understandable!

Comment: @MiguelStevens in your code you show us that `BLOCK` is `100% x 100%` but in your images it's just a small white element... Hope you understand what I don't understand.

Comment: I understand. And your code is ok! i'll figure it out and accept this one :) thanks